# Backbone change events on collection, why it works?

Tags: json, events, backbone.js

Why  event "change" works on model comment 1? How fix it? If I delete line ('comment': []),
events 'change' not work.
I understand that it is because I use array, but I need to use it, but I do not have an event, if nothing has changed in him. Thanks/

---

> create new collection

```
var commentCollection = new VPRS.Comment.CommentCollection([
  {
    "id": "comment1",
    "questionId": "post1",
    "name": "Alex",
    "text": "text 1",
    "comment":[]
  },
  {
    "id": "comment2",
    "questionId": "post1",
    "name": "Alex",
    "text": "Text2"
  }
]);


----------

    json = [
      {
        "id": "comment1",
        "questionId": "post1",
        "name": "Alex",
        "text": "text 1",
        "comment":[]
      },
      {
        "id": "comment2",
        "questionId": "post1",
        "name": "Alex",
        "text": "Text2"
     }]

--------------
wallItemCollection.on('change', function (model) {
  console.log('model change')
}
 ------------
wallItemCollection.fetch({
  update: true,
  merge: true,
  success: function () {
    console.log('fetch compleate')
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you doing that should trigger a `'change:comment'` event?

Comment: nothing. Json data = data in model, but 'change event' trigger.

Comment: So you're, more or less, calling `m.set('comment', [ ])` and it is triggering a `"change"` event that you don't think should be triggered?

Comment: m.set('comment', [ ]) - before fetch, after fetch array comment not changed.. Maybe I explained that that is not the case, and my English is not very good, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does the collection's model look like? Does it have any defaults?